# Constructing a connection from local data

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, connections

The proof that any vector bundle $E \rightarrow M$ has a connection $\nabla$ uses a partition of unity subordinate to some cover $\mathcal{U}$ consisting of local trivialisations of $E$. It essentially exploits the fact that the trivial bundle has a connection given by the operator $d$. I've also seen a similar style of construction for proving that every Riemannian manifold has a connection compatible with its metric.

Can this be generalised? I.e. can we construct *any* connection using a partition of unity?

A better question might be to ask, if we have some connection $\nabla$ on $E$, is there always some local data from which we can construct $\nabla$ using a partition of unity?

Comment: Well, yeah, but it seems that one does not benefit much from it. You could always cover $M$ by the sets $U_\alpha$ and consider the local connections $\nabla|_{U_\alpha}$. Gluing these with the aid of any partition of unity will recover $\nabla$.

Comment: What about the overlapping points? Is there something that guarantees smoothness?